# Extract bibliographic references from pdf files to a bib file

Tags: pdf

Is there a software which can parse pdfs and extract  bibliographic references? ACM DL is a web service which can give that info like here: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=296806.296823&coll=ACM&dl=ACM&CFID=98288669&CFTOKEN=12911537
Mendeley's current release can't do this, would someone confirm: [link](http://feedback.mendeley.com/forums/4941-mendeley-feedback/suggestions/834313-version-0-9-7-does-not-extract-references-from-the)

> Hello - This feature was removed in
>   0.9.7 because it was consuming a fair amount of resources (client and server
>   side) without providing enough value.
>   We plan to re-introduce it in an
>   improved form in future

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic parsing of citation text in academic references](http://superuser.com/questions/24081/automatic-parsing-of-citation-text-in-academic-references)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old thread, but if people are still interested in being able to do this, I recently created a bookmarklet that reads a PDF url (needs to be a public URL, not behind a paywall) and extracts the bibliographic references as either a BibTeX file or .RIS file (Endnote)

The cited documents don't necessarily have to be in a named 'References' section at the end of the paper, they can also be in footnotes.

The tools is called Scholarcy bookmarklet and you can get it here:

https://www.scholarcy.com/bookmarklets

Answer (score 0):

I've read that [mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) can do this, but I have not used it.

Answer (score 0):

the following site can extract all references and citations from a PDF file:

http://www.webmire.com/free-online-science-journal-manuscript-research-tools-software/pdf-references-citations-bibliography-extract-copy-save-export-adobe/

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for the answer. Generally you want to detail the information from a site instead of just dumping a link, since links have a habit of going bad after a while, and then your answer becomes useless.